# Combining two rotations

Tags: 3d, rotations

I'm working on a project, where I have to perform rotations of a point which is on the surface of a sphere of radius 1, around the center of the sphere.

In order to do so, I have a function, let's call it $U$, that is parametrized by 3 angles (real numbers) $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\lambda$, and that performs the following operations on its input: it performs a rotation on $z$ of $\phi$ radians, then a rotation over $y$ of $\theta$ radians, and finally a last rotation, again on $z$, of $\lambda$ radians.

In short: $U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) := R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) R_z(\lambda)$.

Now here is my question: if I successively apply U with angles $\theta_1, \phi_1, \lambda_1$, and then with other angles $\theta_2, \phi_2, \lambda_2$, is there a method to find which angles $\theta, \phi, \lambda$ would have led to the same rotation in only one application of the function, and if so, how ?

Comment: By $R_z(\phi)$ do you mean $R_x(\phi)$?

Comment: Yes, you can find a solution, but that might not be unique.

Comment: Arnaud Mortier: No, it really is $R_z(\phi)$. I am taking that $U$ function from a paper, and have to stick with it.

Comment: And @Andrei: The non-uniqueness of the result is not a problem (a deterministic solution to the problem would be preferable, in this case, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express rotations as matrices. Their combination is found by matrix multiplication.

In your case

> it performs a rotation on $z$ of $\phi$ radians, then a rotation over
>   $y$ of $\theta$ radians, and finally a last rotation, again on $z$, of
>   $\lambda$ radians.

we have:

\begin{align}
U 
&= R_z(\lambda) \, R_y(\theta) \, R_z(\phi) \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\lambda & -\sin\lambda & 0 \\
\sin\lambda & \cos\lambda  & 0 \\
0        & 0         & 1
\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\
0          & 1 & 0 \\
\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi  & 0 \\
0        & 0         & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\lambda & -\sin\lambda & 0 \\
\sin\lambda & \cos\lambda  & 0 \\
0        & 0         & 1
\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta \cos\phi & -\cos\theta \sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\phi            & \cos\phi             & 0 \\
\sin\theta \cos\phi & -\sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}  
\\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\lambda \cos\theta \cos\phi - \sin\lambda \sin\phi &
-\cos\lambda \cos\theta \sin\phi - \sin\lambda \cos\phi &
-\cos\lambda \sin\theta \\
\sin\lambda \cos\theta \cos\phi + \cos\lambda \sin\phi & 
-\sin\lambda \cos\theta \sin\phi + \cos\lambda \cos\phi & 
-\sin\lambda \sin\theta \\
\sin\theta \cos\phi &
-\sin\theta \sin\phi & 
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}  
\end{align}
This results in a single $3 \times 3$ matrix.

If you have two of those transformations $U_1$ and $U_2$ then the composition is given by the matrix product
$$
U_2 U_1
$$
One would have to calculate the resulting matrices and then check if it is possible to easily read the angles from the result.

Comment: I already did the matrix transformation, but have no clue how to read the angles from the resulting matrix

Comment: You can calculate $U_2 U_1$ for your given parameter sets and then try to fit that to a new matrix $U$. E.g. the last element is $\cos \theta$ and you should get the resulting $\theta=\arccos U_{33}$. Then use e.g. $U_{23}$ and $U_{32}$ to recover the resulting $\lambda$ and $\phi$. It is possible that there are several solutions.

Comment: Note that you have a sign issue. In the rotation matrix around $y$ axis the $+\sin$ is in the upper corner.

Comment: @Andrei: You could be right, if I compare to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations). No I idea what 4rzael uses. I would suggest to check the calculation anyways. :-)

Comment: @mvw That's exactly what I was looking at :)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of details about this subject are in the Wikipedia article [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). It seems to me that Euler angles are not a good way to parametrize 3D rotations. As an alternative, you can use 
quaternions as in the Wikipedia article [Quaternion and spatial rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) and just multiply  quaternions in order to perform 3D rotations. An ambiguity is that a quaternion and its negative give the same rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the rotation matrix in terms of [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix). $$R(\phi,\theta,\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}R_{11}& R_{12} &R_{13}\\R_{21}& R_{22} &R_{23}\\R_{31}& R_{32} &R_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$

First calculate the inner most angle. If $R_{31}$ and $R_{32}$ are both zero, use $\lambda=0$. Otherwise $$\tan\lambda=\frac{R_{32}}{-R_{31}}$$ You can use the $\arctan2$ function
$$\lambda=\arctan2 (R_{32},-R_{31})$$

Now calculate $$R'(\phi,\theta)=R(\phi,\theta,\lambda)R^{-1}_z(\lambda)=R(\phi,\theta,\lambda)R_z(-\lambda)$$

If you do the calculations right, you get $\phi=\arctan2(-R'_{12},R'_{22})$
and $\theta=\arctan2(-R'_{31},R'_{33})$